# How to find out record using where condition in Redis List?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using [cloud structure redis](https://github.com/neuecc/CloudStructures) library for redis cache and redis list.

```
// Settings should holds in static variable
public static class RedisServer
{
    public static readonly RedisSettings Default = new RedisSettings("127.0.0.1");
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var mylist = new RedisList<Person>(RedisServer.Default, "test-list-key");
await mylist.LeftPush(new[] { new Person { Name = "Tom" , Age = 12 }, new Person { Name = "Mary" , Age = 23} });
```

> I want to find out record from `mylist` whose `Name=Tom and Age=12`

Comment: I'm not sure SE.Redis is a good tag here; CloudStructures is a completely different API built on top of it, and nothing in the question touches SE.Redis

Comment: because CloudStructures internally uses `StackExchange.Redis` library

Comment: @Neo I believe that Marc is the library's author ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis *simply doesn't work like that*. You can't do the equivalent of `where ...` when querying a list. You can push, pop, and query ranges, etc ([here's the full list of "list" commands](http://redis.io/commands#list)). There *is* a "what is the index of [content] in [list]", but for that you need to know *the entire payload of the object* (in the exact same form), not just individual pieces. You *can* build indexes *manually* inside redis, but: this is a relatively advanced topic.

Comment: thanks but how can I do it in my case? I tried like `var result = await mylist.Equals(PersonObj)` it returns bool :( and others are not working as expected `GetByIndex` etc

Comment: can you share any sample code or link for the same?

Comment: @Neo again "Redis simply doesn't work like that" - no, I can't share sample code, because *that isn't how redis works*

Comment: ok got you will check any other work around for similar condition clause

Comment: *if you know the entire object* - enough to reconstruct *exactly* the right payload, then *at the redis layer*, yes: you can ask for the index of an element - but that won't help you *filter* or *search*, because you'd already need to know everything - and even if it did: I can't tell you how (or even if) CloudStructures exposes that API

Comment: Josiah's book might point you in the right direction: https://redislabs.com/ebook/redis-in-action - part 2 chapter 7, maybe

Comment: Great stuff thanks lot if any blog or weblink is there it will.be useful too . Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Like Marc Gravell has stated on his own answer, Redis doesn't support *querying* but it can be tailored in a way that it can act as a raw data index. This is the reason of providing data structures like lists, sets, sorted sets, hashes...

For example, if you want to retrieve persons with a specific name are age, you need to index the data in a way that you can later get the entire entity that matches the whole criteria.

1. Store your JSON strings in a hash where the key is an unique identifier and value is the JSON text. Alternatively you can store key-value pairs in the global Redis keyspace using a simple `set` command.
2. If you want to get persons which have a `Name` and `Age`, you can store persons in another hash where the keys will be in some format like `<Name>:<Age>` and the value will be the person's unique identifier: `Tom:12` => `1` (where `1` is the unique identifier`.
3. Once you've already created that second hash to support the *name and age* criteria, it's just about executing a `hget persons:name-and-age Tom:12` to get Tom's unique identifier, and later execute another `hget` to get the JSON: `hget persons 1` (where `1` is the unique identifier got from the hash of *name and age* search criteria.

In summary

```
hset persons 1 "JSON here"
hset persons:bycriteria:name-and-age Tom:12 1

hset persons 2 "JSON here"
hset persons:bycriteria:name-and-age Matias:31 1
```

Now I want to get Tom with age 12:

```
// pseudo-code
// "Tom" and "12" may come from C# variables that were set by who knows
// what... For example, a WebAPI request that got these search criteria
// arguments...
tomId = hget persons:bycriteria:name-and-age Tom:12
tom = hget persons tomId
```

This is just a possible approach to index data on Redis and later being able to get data by some predefined criteria in Redis.

I suggest you this article on official Redis site: http://redis.io/topics/indexes

Comment: exactly thanks for more elaboration :) I have used Redis Dictionary , I think that is more useful. but as you mention I dont know how to make a key with multiple fields like name+age , can you give me small example or any blog link

Comment: @Neo Double-check my answer and I believe that you'll need to go further yourself from now. Your project may define its own requirements and covering each case wouldn't be an answer to a question but providing the full solution!

Comment: @Neo I've checked that you request blog links or whatever in Marc's answer as well... In StackOverflow, asking for off-site resources is off-topic and would be a good reason to close a Q&A. I really believe that both Marc's answer and my one are enough to give you hints on how to solve your underlying issue :)

Comment: yea very true i had managed it well , thanks for your inputs it really helps :)